# regex to add a space between every special character (except \) and any number or alphabet (alphnum). Secluding SINGLR special characters in a

Tags: python, regex

I have a cleaning process in which I go step by step.

1. Increase the spacing between any special character and any alphanum except `\`. for example `x+y` becomes `x + y`, `-2` becomes `- 2`, `--hello` becomes `-- hello`, `hello--43world` becomes `hello -- 43 world` BUT `\(` , `\\` and `\n` are as they are.
2. Then I want to remove every special character which is repeating itself more than 1 times . also except `\` as it can be `\\` types in my data.
3. Then in the third phase, I want to remove multiple consecutive special characters like `._.1` becomes `1` , `**- 43` becomes `43` but `x \-3` becomes `x /- 3` and also again excluding `\`.

So the biggest problem I see here is **Insert a space in the point 1?**. I can make a `list` out the `string`, Run a loop and If I see a special character at `ith` position, I'll insert a `' '` at `i+1th` and then join but it'll be too heavy for my system.

for the second part, I can use the expression which I came up with `([^a-zA-Z0-9\\ ])\1{1,}` but it fails for some use use cases too. (Can you please confirm if this is the right thing to do?)

For third part, I used `([^a-zA-Z0-9\\ ]{3,})` but I think it failed with my use case and when I used it again, it started working I don't know how and Why just like the First one. and The third one seems to do all the work except adding a space.

Basically, I want

```
hello--- (x+y-2/5=6 ) +_) h__EEL__l-++o //x \\#1---+++1 \\nHello x^^4 3-------6  \n \\n \( hello \)  1+_+1 -+-1+=- +_\\n))_x+=0
```

to be something like

```
hello  ( x + y - 2 / 5 = 6 )   h EEL l o x \\# 1 1 \\nHello x 4 3 6  \n \\n \( hello \)  1 1  1  +_\\n x+=0
```

Comment: I think you basically want to create a tokenizer. Consider implementing a finite state machine that decides what to do based on each next character it sees. (using a loop rather than a regex).

Comment: Can You give me an example?